# How to Group product based on brand & fetch min price product in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-orm

I have two table one is brand and other is product now product have 1 foreign of brand_id.

1 brand has multiple products at different prices.

now, the problem is I want to fetch only 1 product for each brand not more than 1 and that 1 product is fetch based on minimum price.
how to achieve it in Django ORM?

Note: If a brand has no product then that brand should not fetch!

here, what I tried but it does not work well.

```
def price_chart(request, category_slug):
    labels = []
    price_data = []
    price_analysis_data = Product.objects.filter(brand__category__category_slug = category_slug).values('brand__brand_name').annotate(
       Min('product_price')
    ).order_by('-product_price')
    for data in price_analysis_data:
        labels.append(data['brand__brand_name'])
        price_data.append(data['product_price'])
    return JsonResponse(data={
        'labels': labels,
        'price_data': price_data,
    })
```

Please suggest me good solution!

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @AKS Mysql database

Comment: There is a solution to use `distinct(*fields)` which only works in postgres. It doesn't have an alternative for Mysql.

Comment: Ohh then there is no solution for this?

Comment: There are some hacks which could be applied. Another question, in the view you are returning labels and price as separate arrays. Do you not need a relation between these two?

Comment: @AKS yes I need a relation between these two.

Comment: Please check the _hacky_ answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can order on the brand name (increasing) and price (decreasing) both:

```
brand_name_to_min_price_map = dict(
    Product.objects.filter(
        brand__category__category_slug=category_slug,
    ).order_by(
        'brand__brand_name', '-product_price',
    ).values_list(
        'brand__brand_name', 'product_price',
    )
)
```

Because we put the values list in a dict, it will create a key value pair (brand name to price). If brand name repeats, the value which come later will override previous value. In this case, for each brand the product price which appears last in the list will be used. Since, we ordered the results in the decreasing order of the product price within each brand, the last price will always be the minimum one.

Comment: it's showing some syntax error near  '-product_price'

Comment: There was a typo because brand_name didn't have end quote. I have fixed it.

Comment: Amazing Man! you did it very well thanks a lot. you are great:)

Comment: 1 more help actually now it's not possible to show data properly see i want to achieve something like this Example 2: Bar Chart with Ajax https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2020/01/19/how-to-use-chart-js-with-django.html

Comment: From the dictionary, you can easily get the keys and values in separate list. If required, you can use `items()` method get them as list.